What is dmic_detect=0 in snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0?
What is dmic_detect=0 in snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 and what are it's states?
It tried searching google but received no answer.
I came across it after fixing an audio problem by adding the line snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 to grub config .
Thanks!

You edited the grub and added a line but now ask what it did?

I'm not worried that it might break anything. I'm more interested in knowing what it does in specific as I can tell that it makes the bootloader identify the audio chipset.

It doesn't make the bootloader do anything, the bootloader will just forward those parameters to the kernel when bootstrapping it. Dmic seems to refer to "Digital microphone(s)", so it appears as those parameters would "disable dection of digital microphones" at a kernel / driver level.

This comment seems to corroborate my hypothesys

The mic works .
